# How to set-up a Typescript class so my Browser AND Node app can use it?

Tags: typescript, module

I have written a web app which is simply 2 separate projects with each in different folders and their own unique files.

The *client* portion is written in Angular 2 (RC-4) using SystemJS Typescript 1.8.10 (as per [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)).
The *server* portion is a simple NodeJS app using Typescript 1.8.10 (as well).

As mentioned each have their own folder and their own unique files (including their own `tsconfig.json` file.)

All is working fine.

But now, I want to use a class `MySharedClass {}` to be used in BOTH of these projects. **How on earth do I do this?**

Sure, I can put a source-code copy in each of the projects (i.e. have 2 copies of the source file), and it builds and runs fine - but that is NOT how we do things.

I thought of creating a 'third' project called 'common' and putting `MySharedClass {}` in there, but I can't do a

`import {MyClass} from "../../../common/my-class";`

in each of my projects because it doesn't seem to reference it when I run it. (I wasn't able to get it to reference the file during run-time as I believe the reason is that you can't reference the file outside the scope of the project ?!?)

Researching around, there does not seem to be an explanation on how to do this - am I missing something obvious?

Please feel free to point me in the right direction as to what people are doing to solve this - is there something I need to learn? I'm quite sure I understand the ES6 module system (as per the recent Typescript ES6 way) as I've been using this method in the projects. I'm not currently using a build tool as I don't require the additional complexity: I'm just using scripts provided in the `package.json` file (as per [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)). Should I need to look into using [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) now?

Comment: " creating a 'third' project called 'common' and putting MySharedClass {} in there " is totally fine. Where do you set the path of compiled js?

Comment: @Zen is right. It is most probably a problem of include path. You can also move all common code in a dedicated package installed as a node_modules in both project.

Comment: @jobou Not certainly. If OP is using Visual Studio the client app is hosted by IIS on localhost and as such, nothing outside the project root can be referenced.

Comment: Yes but most of the time you have a gulp (or other task runner) script which makes copy of your file in a dist/build folder which is served by the server. So in this case, it would be a problem of include path. But yes here, we can assume that the root document of the web server would be the client folder and the common dependencies are outside and so not serviceable by the web server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Yes @Zen it is a problem of the include path. I'm not using Visual Studio and using Node as the webserver (I was using [Atom](https://atom.io/) but it keeps hanging so its back to [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) I go...). Yes @jobou you're right saying that the common dependencies are outside the folder and thus so not serviceable by the web server. I've solved my issue by (as @Zen says) by creating a third project called 'common' and when I build each of the other projects, I just run a simple script which copies the necessary files over to the appropriate folders so the other projects can use the class.